# why TailerListener executor prints the lines in the file twice?

Tags: java, file, executor, taillistener

I want to tail a text file I want to use Executor for this purpose, The problem is whenever I run the following code I prints each line twice i-e prints the complete file line by line and skips the last line than start printing the same lines again, I tried to use thread instead of Executor it works fine there.
Plus its not printing the last line of the text file.

```
   public static void helper()
{
    TailerListener listener = new TailListener();
    Tailer tailer = Tailer.create(new File("E:\\terilium\\code\\productive-coder-si-bookstore-master\\kafka_runtime\\testing_files\\test.txt"),
            listener, SLEEP);
    Executor executor = new Executor()
    {
        public void execute(Runnable command)
        {
            command.run();
        }
    };
    executor.execute(tailer);

}  class TailListener extends  TailerListenerAdapter
{
    public void handle(String line)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

I want the output same as the text written in text file.

Is this the behavior of `Executor` or I am missing something I don't understand why this thing is that problematic.

Thanks

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbPPU.png)

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate lines are printed because you have two threads monitoring and printing the same line:

1. Thread created by the static method `Tailer.create(...)`.
2. Thread created by the executor.

You may want to get rid of the executor and just let the `Thread.create` write it once.

You would have to ensure the parent thread does not exit. A crude way to do it is `while(true){}`

```
TailerListener listener = new TailListener();
Tailer tailer = Tailer.create(new File("E:\\terilium\\code\\productive-coder-si-bookstore-master\\kafka_runtime\\testing_files\\test.txt"),
        listener, SLEEP);
while(true){}
```